# Menu list in IE6 sub not dropping

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

i know that ie6 has a problem with :hover visibilty and child selectors, but cannot see why my sub menu is not dropping? i have included code and would be grateful if someone could tell me where my error is? this is a follow on from replies recevied in an earlier post. you will notice that i have tried the htc file behavior and that is not working for me either. thanks

```
<ul id="navigation" class="nav-main">
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a href="#">Freebies</a>
          <ul class="nav-sub">
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/backgrounds/">Backgrounds</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/buttons/">Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/graphics/">Graphics</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/html-css/">HTML &amp; CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/icons/">Icons</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/psd/">PSD</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/templates/">Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>    
          </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="list"><a href="#">About</a>
          <ul class="nav-sub">
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/about/">AboutUs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/commercial-use/">Commercial Use</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/about/terms-of-use/">Terms Of Use</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>

            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/advertise/">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>


        </ul>


body    {

    behavior: url(csshover3.htc);
}

#navigation {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    clear:both;
    width:999px;
    height:51px;
    background: #d6eaf8 url(../images/dropdown-bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
}


ul.nav-main,
ul.nav-main li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


ul.nav-main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
}

ul.nav-main li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;

}


ul.nav-main li.hover,
ul.nav-main li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/dropdown-bg-hover.gif) repeat-x left top;

}



ul.nav-main li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block ;
    height: 100%;
    color: #999;
    font: 14px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url(../images/separator.gif) no-repeat right center;

}

ul.nav-main li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    font: 14px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.nav-main li a:hover {
    color:#D6D6D6;

}



ul.nav-main *.list {
    padding-right: 22px;
    background: url(../images/navigation-arrow.gif) no-repeat right top;
}



ul.nav-sub {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    padding:10px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    background: #353535 url(../images/dropdown-list-bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;

}


ul.nav-sub li {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 27px;
    float: none;
    width:145px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
    background: none;

}

ul.nav-sub li a {
    list-style:none;
    display:none;
    padding: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
    height: 15px;
    float: none;
    width:145px;
    background: none;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

ul.nav-main li:hover ul.nav-sub {     display:none; /* OR display:list-item */ }
```

Comment: Could you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML and CSS? It would be much easier to see your markup.

Comment: @chris i have updated my code with my html. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearing in mind that you're already using [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html)..

Without actually testing in IE6, there is *one* problem that I can see:

```
ul.nav-main li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

That's using `>` (the [direct child selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector)), which is [not implemented in IE6](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector#compatibilitysection).

Try replacing that selector with `ul.nav-main li:hover ul` or `ul.nav-main li:hover .nav-sub`.

Comment: using ul.nav-main li:hover .nav-sub has made the sub appear but no list within the sub.

Comment: made a slight addition to your code and it now works. changed ul.nav-sub li a from display:none to display:block and voila, one dropdown in ie6 without js :-) i love it when a plan comes together :-) thanks for youe help

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you sorted it out. I wasn't looking forward to spending time with IE6.

Answer (score 1):

If your content is already around anchor tags you can try changing your CSS to attach the hover property to the anchors instead of the li's. It will likely still be problematic however.

If this doesn't work try adding display: inline-block to the anchor tags. Otherwise you'll have to hack it with javascript.

```
<li><a>content</a></li>

ul.nav-main li a:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;

}


ul.nav-main li a.hover,
ul.nav-main li a:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/dropdown-bg-hover.gif) repeat-x left top;

}
```

Something like that. The hover property for anything besides anchor tags is problematic in early versions of IE. You could also alternatively try something like this:

http://www.danvega.org/blog/index.cfm/2008/1/1/CSS-hover-selector

Comment: do i not already have anchor tags? <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/html-css/">HTML &amp; CSS</a></li> or have i misunderstood you? thanks

Comment: You cannot use the :hover pseudo class for anything other than anchor tags with IE6 without hacking it with JS. I didn't see your HTML before I posted that - but the solution is still the same. Edited answer for posted HTML.

Comment: hmm, so JS or jquery is the only way to go with this? are there any alternatives as the link that you posted i am already using the htc file method and that is not working. thanks

Comment: `body { behavior: url(csshover3.htc); }` - he's already using this: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some Javascsript for IE6.

`li:hover` is your problem. IE6 only supports hover on anchor tags (and probably some form elements, I can't remember now, but definately not `<li>`s)

Comment: do you have links for examples to this? and how would that effect users that have JS disabled? thanks

Comment: `body { behavior: url(csshover3.htc); }` - he's already using this: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

Comment: I don't have an example to hand. The idea would be to replicate what the :hover psuedo class does. So for IE6 do something like use mouseover and mouseout* events to add and remove a class (probably "hover") from the elements you want to simulate hover on. 

As for IE6 users that don't have JS turned on. You'll probably only have about 2 of them, but you have three options, forget about them, have the menu expanded by default (use JS to hide them), or have secondary menus on the pages under the top-level menu items. 

* I forget what the events are in IE, is it onmouseover or onmouseenter?

Comment: @thirtydot I had missed that.